# Selecting image for imageview1 at left and imageview2 at right fixed

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm still new here in android. Please help me. I manage to put the imageview to the left and right side of my Layout. My problem is when I select an image for imageview2 it passes the image to imageview1 and still the imageview2 can be seen from the right side.

I need to do is when I select an image for imageview2 it should be fixed at the right side. I think I have problems with my code in java?

Here is my code for xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/insert_bg"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="15dip"
android:paddingBottom="15dip"
>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_left"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:src="@drawable/insert_ci" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_center"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
     android:scaleType="fitEnd"
     android:src="@drawable/insert_ci"
     android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And this code for java.

```
package com.prototype;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
//import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
//import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity3 extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 2;

private String selectedImagePath;
private String selectedImagePath2;
private ImageView img;
private ImageView img2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open_project);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_left);
    img2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_center);

    addImageViewClickListener();
    addImageView2ClickListener();
}
public void addImageViewClickListener()
{
ImageView btnNavigator1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_left);
btnNavigator1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) 

            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select character image for right side."), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }

            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //}
        });
}





public void addImageView2ClickListener()
{
ImageView btnNavigator2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_center);
btnNavigator2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) 

            {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select character image for left side."), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }

            //@Override
            //public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //}
        });
}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) 
        {
            //File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Database/");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}

public void onActivityResult2(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) 
        {
            //File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Database/");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath2);
            img2.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}


public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

The problem that I was talking about is like this.http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/6sa6.png/

[printscreen image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/31/6sa6.png/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for two imageViews. So your images will not overlap

```
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_left"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it was still like that.when i select an image for imageview2 it is pass to imageview1 or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Imageview make `0dp` to your android:layout_width@

```
 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_left"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
     android:scaleType="fitStart"
     android:src="@drawable/icon" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_center"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="2"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
     android:scaleType="fitEnd"
     android:src="@drawable/icon"
     android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />
```

**Update**

Create one more folder named `layout-land` and keep same `xml` inside with appropriate changes, hope it works.

Comment: it was still like that.the image i load for imageview2 is somewhat or i don't know pass to imageview1  I don't know if my problem is in xml or in java.

Comment: Not able to access image link, can you post in your question itself?

Comment: I used your code and the positioning is alright but when i select an image for imageview2 i can still see the imageview2 and the selected image was inputed in imageview1. Sorry if I don't explain myself clear. I was having problem with my grammar

Comment: Can you post your output image in your question instead link.

Comment: I can't add the printscreen it says i need 10 reputation.

Comment: be back going to school first.

Answer (score 0):

The image is getting stretched because of the weight mentioned.

The `android:layout_weight` for the first imageView is 1 and that is for second imageView is 2.

This leads to taking 2/3rd of the screen by the the second imageView and the rest by the first.

Adjust the weights and you can overcome the issue.

Comment: I tried adjusting it to 1 and .5 but the result is still there.when i select an image for imageview2 the image that i need to be on the right side was at the left side and the imageview2 is still be seen.
i think the image was passed to imageview1

Comment: could you remove the weight and try

Comment: the problem still exist.the image i selected was inputed in imageview1
http://postimg.org/image/iawr6mmn1/